# Rails fragment caching with dynamic content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, optimization, dynamic

I'm working on a social networking app where users can follow each other.

To speed things up I added fragment caching on users' preview and full page views.

The good news is the app became really fast.
The bad one is that I started experiencing bugs related to follow buttons.

In fact all users preview and full page views have one follow block that can have different 4 states whether the user is logged in, seeing his profile, seeing someone else's followed already or seeing someone else's not followed already.

To address this issue I ended having a different cache version of each user's preview and full page views in each of the 4 different states (= 8 different cached fragment for each user). The issue is now gone but I can't help but think this is far away from being optimal.

Then I heard about [Ryan Bates' Railscast on dynamic fragment caching](http://railscasts.com/episodes/169-dynamic-page-caching-revised) and started thinking.

Maybe I could load just the follow button through ajax. But then ...

- Should I make one request for each button ?
- Should I gather them all up to prevent having a lot of requests ? How ?
- Is there a better way ?

What do you think ? :)

Comment: Better late than never, right ? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I make one request for each button ?

No, you should bundle them together, because it would be much faster than one request per button

> Should I gather them all up to prevent having a lot of requests ? How ?

Yes, you know all objects displayed on one page, so you should be able to collect all id's of users to be followed and ask for their followed state.

> Is there a better way ?

Nothing that I can think of, but that doesn't mean there isn't a better way.